# Bpy blender 3.1 geometry nodes set property in python

Tags: python

[image]

I'm trying to set "Rotation", I can set a keyframe, but want to set it to (1,1,1) as a vector, but I cannot do it.

The keyframe insert works:

```
bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].keyframe_insert(data_path='nodes["Instance on Points"].inputs[5].default_value', frame=2 )
```

but that's it

Answer (score 2):

nvm, Zanqdo on Blenderchat told me to copy full data path and that would be where i set the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just set the value without adding a keyframe

```py
bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].node_group.nodes["Instance on Points"].inputs[5].default_value = ROTATION
```

replacing ROTATION with a 3-tuple of (x, y, z) rotation values would work.

Comment: that's the full data path, yes.

Comment: but note that the above code only works if you don't change the name of the modifier or the name of the _instance on points_ node; and will stop working if the devs reorganize the inputs to the _instance on points_ node.  the bpy api for accessing nodes is very fragile.